# How to assign a variable in mathematica to just the output of an expression?

Tags: functions, function-construction

So, say I wanted to assign a function `J[x_, y_] :={D[system, x], D[system, y]}//Transpose` where `system` is some system of equations. This seems to assign J to be the expression itself and the variables x,y are the variables it drives with respect to. How can I get it to assign to just the output of `{D[system, x], D[system, y]}` so that I don't get an error message when I try to plug actual numbers into the function?

Comment: See the differences between `SetDelayed` (`:=`) and `Set` (`=`): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487 Most of the time functions are best defined with `SetDelayed`, but this is an instance where `Set` may be more appropriate.

Comment: It looks like you  instead should be using `D[system, {{x, y}}]` or `Grad[sys, {x, y}]`.